# Is it possible to get a value using Interpolation inside array?

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I am trying to get a value in html using interpolation.
For that i use interpolation inside the array[] like `sessions[{{item.sessionNumber}}]` to get the index.
Still I cant get the result

```html
<ion-item class="item" text-center no-lines *ngFor="let item of token let i=index">
  Time:{{item.client[0].sessionDetails.sessions[{{item.sessionNumber}}].startTime}}
</ion-item>
```

Comment: Why double interpolation is there, it is not required at all, one is enough, the outside one. And can you put more detail like data structure that would help us to identify solution.

Comment: inside this sessions[{{item.sessionNumber}}] this interpolation to get another value here to get the starttime from array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your example, you do not need to use interpolation inside interpolation.

Since the template syntax is JavaScript like, the following should work.

```
<ion-item class="item" text-center no-lines *ngFor="let item of token let i=index">
  Time:{{ item.client[0].sessionDetails.sessions[item.sessionNumber].startTime }}
</ion-item>
```

This assumes you have an object in the component with the following structure:

```
item = {
  client: [{ 
    sessionDetails: {
      sessions: [ { startTime: "12:00"} ]
    }   
  }],
  sessionNumber: 0
};
```

Answer (score 0):

call a function and send the index. you can't use interpolation like this